# How execle() system call works?

Tags: c, operating-system, system-calls

I am trying to understand this system call (execle()) but I don't know how it works. I don't know how to use char* envp[], which we have to pass it as a parameter. I have tried this but it doesn't work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    int pid;
    int* status;
    char* envp[] = {"/usr/lib", 0};
    //Child process
    if((pid=fork())==0)
    {
        printf("I'm the child and I'm going to list...\n");
        execle("/bin/ls", "ls", "-l", "-a", 0, envp);
        printf("Error\n");
    }
    //Parent process
    else
    {
        printf("I'm the parent...\n");
        wait(status);
    }
    printf("Child status: %d\n", *status);
}
```

I don't know what I should put in char* envp[].

Comment: `envp` is for environment variables, and they are inherited from the parent environment, so there is no really need for that. Do you really want to use it to alter the environment? If so, what variable are you trying to set exactly?

Comment: I don't know what I should put in envp to run the program properly. I have put /usr/lib because I want to list the files in that folder, but I think that I don't have a correct knowledge about envp variable...

Comment: Read the manual [exec(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html) then read [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html). Read also [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/)

Comment: No, that's the command line, not the environment. Environment is the set of variables such as `PATH=/bin:/usr/bin` and so on. The words after the command, as in `/binls /usr/lib` is the command line and is specified as the `arg` parameter.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. But in what cases could be useful this system call (execle()), instead of execl()?

Comment: Well, in cases you want the new process to have this exact environment instead of the parent one. This is useful in security sensitive applications, login managers and such, that create new sessions. Normal applications should inherit the parent environment, so it is better just use `execl()` or maybe `execlp()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But in what cases could be useful this
>   system call (execle()), instead of execl()?
>                       – Víctor

Well, in cases you want the new process to have this exact environment instead of the parent one. This is useful in security sensitive applications, login managers and such, that create new sessions. Normal applications should inherit the parent environment, so it is better just use `execl()` or maybe `execlp()`.
                    – rodrigo